# How to restrict user to allow only numeric and optionally two decimal number

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to restrict user input to allow only a integer or a two decimal number with a limit from `0` till `99999.99`.

Tried with script but not succeed in all scenarios.
also, required this should work with mobile OS also.

```
     $('#txtamount').keydown(function (event) {

                if (event.which == 8 || event.which == 9 || event.which == 37 || event.which == 38 || event.which == 46) {
                    //event.preventDefault();
                    return true;
                }

                alert('final' + event.which);
                if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                    return false;
                    event.preventDefault();
                }

                var text = $(this).val();

                if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) && (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2)) {
                    return false;
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
```

Tried with below stuff but, not working to restrict special chars.

http://jsfiddle.net/jquerydeveloper/LmHkD/

Comment: toFixed(2)  is what you want

Comment: Its optioanlly, two decimal.user can input numeric in else.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "write code for me" request.

Comment: Show us your code thus far.

Comment: adding script , give me a section.

Comment: can any one please add comments.

Comment: you might have better look doing this on some sort of submit/complete even, rather then on every keypress

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using keycode detection, probably better to use a regex and onchange, rather than keydown.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="number"]').change(function (e) {
        var valueEntered = $(this).val()
        var regex = /^[0-9]{1,5}(\.[0-9]{2})?$/
        if (!regex.test(valueEntered)){
            $(this).val(''); //set value to nil, consider also display message
        }
    });
});
```

I'd also modify the input type to be a number, rather than text:

```
<input name="number" type="number" value=" " />
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LmHkD/259/

Note, this will just get you started, you may need to update the regex for your exact scenario

Comment: How to make it as follow - 1) only allow numeric 2) optionally allow (2 decimal places) but not mandatory   ? can you please make it here.

Comment: edited to add begin/end of string which should match your criteria